# Process uses large amount of memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I'm building an Android app that parses a pretty big XML file (around 500 items) using SAX and then rendering it to a ListView via a custom adapter.  I'm parsing the XML to a List I created, which I then pass the List object to my custom adapter (Not all 500 items are added to the List, usually around 50 or so).

Everything works fine and the app seems pretty responsive on my Nexus One, but when I view the app in Settings, under Running -> "show cached processes", the process can be using anywhere from 40MB-70MB of memory.  Not sure if I have a memory leak somewhere, or what that means, but it seems pretty high to me.

Comment: what is the size of xml file?

Comment: The best way to profile and hunt for memory leaks, would be using heap dump in Android Tool and MAT (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). Here's an additional blog post about this: http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2009/04/analyzing-memory-usage-off-your-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even at 500 items unless your XML is very redundant or unless each item is huge you should be fine on the file side of things.

What you can do is you can check whats making allocations inside DDMS (From Eclipse: Open DDMS perspective => Click on your app name in the list under your device => allocation tracker tab => start tracking => get allocations after your list renders).

A little more info about what kind of app your running might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try looking at the allocations.  The app is basically an RSS reader.  Like I mentioned, it parses a pretty big RSS feed (1.32MB file size) and does some filtering on it and displays a ListView of 20-100 items.

Comment: I ran the eclipse allocation tracker.  I'm not sure how to read it though.  What exactly am I looking for that would indicate a memory leak?

Comment: A memory leak would basically look like the same allocation happening from the same function and not being removed (garbage collected). If the garbage collector is constantly running it means your code makes too many allocations. If your garbage collector is NOT running and your heap size is growing you have a leak. Run 4 or so tests and see if there are any re-occurring allocations happening. If you see the same function making the same allocations and NO garbage is being collected then you are leaking.

Comment: gotcha.  Thanks for the response!